# Regex to include a url path but exclude if contains

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm writing a google analytics regex to try excluding the success and failure page of my checkout process but still match the checkout page.

I need to match:

```
/checkout/onepage/
/checkout/onepage#
/checkout/onepage/index
```

and Not match:

```
/checkout/onepage/success
/checkout/onepage/failure
```

Best I could come up with was:

```
/(?:.*checkout\/onepage.*)(?!success|failure)/
```

IF you could help explain it a little as well id be very grateful.

Comment: does that regex work for you?

Comment: Use Exclude filters to get rid of the unwanted URLs. See https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034832?hl=en

Comment: No the regex doesnt work in Google analytics, its matches all.
Also I cant use the filters as its a cart funnel, no filter options just regex, partial match or exact match.